# AngularJS animation makes hidden element appear when the page is loaded

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-animation

I have a hidden component in a directive and yet when the page is loaded, the hidden element appears for the duration of the animation, which should only be triggered when the component's model is set to visible.

In this example I set the component to **ng-hide="true"** permanently, and when the page is loaded it still appears for half a second. In my real program the directive is much more complicated, so I placed the template in its own file, the problem doesn't appear if I just put it in a string.

I tried adding **style="display:none"** to the template's content, but then it doesn't react to model changes later.

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <style>
    .overlay {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: black;

        transition: all linear 0.5s;
    }
    .overlay.ng-hide {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    angular.module("myApp", ['ngAnimate'])
        .directive("overlay", function() {
            return {
                replace: true,
                templateUrl: "overlay.html"
            };
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <overlay></overlay>
</body>
</html>
```

overlay.html:

```
<div class="overlay" ng-hide="true"></div>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/tYLkGwPJtFPxH2ES6qIe?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the opposite using `ng-class` instead. Switch your CSS so the overlay only shows when you add a class `show`:

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0;

    transition: all linear 0.5s;
}
.overlay.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Then just use the `ng-class` directive on your overlay, change the `false` value to whatever expression you have in mind.

```
<div class="overlay" ng-class="{show : false}"></div>
```

Here's the [Forked Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pktrZZLueOM068iZ1B3e?p=preview)

Comment: This was probably the more elegant solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a link function that adds a `display: none` property to the overlay element temporarily and then removed afterwards when the `ng-hide` directives kicks in by watching the `ng-hide` initial value and then removing the `display: none` property and deregistering the watcher.

Something like this:
**[FORKED PLUNKER](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)**

```
    .directive("overlay", function() {
        return {
            templateUrl: "overlay.html",
            link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
              elem.css('display', 'none');
              var dereg = scope.$watch(attr.ngHide, function(value) {
                elem.css('display', '');
                dereg();
              });
            }
        };
    });
```

Note that I have removed the `replace` property, it is depreciated in angular 3.0 and above. **[Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)**